# Access windows EBS Volume from EC2 linux as folder

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a windows EC2 Server in AWS and I have attached two EBS volumes to that to store pictures and videos on that. Now I need to access those videos and images from the linux server as a network path.

For example, If the local ip address of the windows EC2 is **10.0.0.12** and folder name is **share**, I want to access this in linux as follows.

\10.0.0.12\share

Is it possible to map the Windows EC2 folders as mentioned above to the linux? If possible, can someone tell me the steps to map it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not store the files in S3 and get easier share options?

Comment: I want to use this  for video streaming using wowza server and I want it to be faster. there were some forum comments saying s3 is slower compare to the EBS volumes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try mounting it via cifs:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/share
mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD //10.0.0.12/share /mnt/share
```

Comment: If I do like this, will I be able to access the shared folder like the following?

//10.0.0.12/share

Comment: No, it will be mounted on (and accessible on) /mnt/share

Comment: Is there any way to access with the IP address via lunux? thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

The [Samba](https://www.samba.org/) project basically provides the Linux server and client software for exposing or consuming Windows shares. The equivalent tool you are looking for here then is the [sbmclient](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/smbclient.1.html). Some simple examples [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SMB-HOWTO-8.html):

> /usr/bin/smbclient \\<ip address>\public mypasswd

The smbmount command, also described in the link earlier shows you how you can mount the share.